# Get modulus and plot complex function

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

I have the following function:

```
freq[a_, b_, t0_, tr_, s_] := -((b E^(-s (b + t0)) (b E^(s (b + t0)) (-1 + 
           b s) UnitStep[-b] - b E^(s t0) UnitStep[b] + 
        E^(s (b - tr)) (E^(s (t0 + tr)) (-1 + b s) UnitStep[-t0] + 
           E^(s tr) (-1 + b s - s t0) UnitStep[t0] - 
           E^(s (t0 + tr)) (-1 + b s) UnitStep[-t0 - tr] + (1 + 
              s (-b + t0 + tr)) UnitStep[t0 + tr])))/(s^2 tr))
```

Now I want to plot the function as follows:

```
Plot[ComplexExpand@Abs@ExpToTrig@freq[0, 1, 0, 10^-6, Iw], {w,0,10^9}]
```

However that doesn't work. I couldn't exact the absolute value of the complex function to plot it.

(w is a real positive number)

Does anyone know how to plot that?

Comment: Iw should have a space in between, or use `I*w`

Comment: @flinty thanks! It took me one hour trying different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by flinty, `Iw` should be `I*w`; and [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html) makes it easier to visualize.

```
freq[a_, b_, t0_, tr_, 
  s_] := -((b E^(-s (b + t0)) (b E^(s (b + t0)) (-1 + b s) UnitStep[-b] - 
        b E^(s t0) UnitStep[b] + 
        E^(s (b - tr)) (E^(s (t0 + tr)) (-1 + b s) UnitStep[-t0] + 
           E^(s tr) (-1 + b s - s t0) UnitStep[t0] - 
           E^(s (t0 + tr)) (-1 + b s) UnitStep[-t0 - tr] + (1 + 
              s (-b + t0 + tr)) UnitStep[t0 + tr])))/(s^2 tr))

LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[Abs@ExpToTrig@freq[0, 1, 0, 10^-6, I*w]], {w, 0, 10^9}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea!